# SonarQube Java Analyser, rule S2183, why should I remove this useless shift?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have written:

```
public static final int MY_GREAT_COLOR = (91 << 16) + (155 << 8) + 213 + (255 << 32);
```

And sonar says:

> New: Squid:S2183 Severity: CRITICAL, Message: Remove this useless shift

Could anybody tell me why? Is that only the fact that there should be no calculations on literals, even if it adds to readability?

Comment: It may be connected with `(255 << 32)`, it doesn't really make sense to do it, because it will be always zero. Try removing it, and see if you get the same error.

Comment: am i the only one, who read the last word in a question wrong?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker: No. :D

Comment: Out of topic, but misread the question a bit.. :) And yes, Sonar is a rude one.

Comment: As a member of SonarSource dev team : @AdamSkywalker hmm we may reword that then :D
Otherwise : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-2183 Doc states clearly why issue is raised. We are currently working on improving reporting issue not only on line but also on columns to precisely point out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess 255 is your alpha channel, in that case I guess you wanted `255 << 24`.

SonarQube doesn't know your intentions, but it has a valid point, as Toby stated.

As for readability, you can also try hexa code (e.g. `0xFF5B9BD5`), many devs are used to that already. Of course, a decimal number would be totally unreadable and ugly.

Answer (score 2):

`255 << 32` overflows a Java (32-bit) `int`, becoming zero.

Do you want a `long`, and `255L << 32`?